# Can't do anything in big table

Tags: select, mariadb, innodb

I'm running a local MariaDB database in a Macbook.
Was testing a table to receive a lot of rows and, at 12million it stopped inserting.
Now I can't insert, delete or truncate the table. The process never ends and eventually stops : "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

I event tried to drop the table, but the result is the same.

Anyone knows what is happening and how to solve it? I'm afraid that this happens in my server, because this table is going to have away more then 12million

table definition:

```
create table _stats_leads_servicos
(
    id_lead           int            null,
    id_servico        int            null,
    id_tipo           char(5)        not null comment '''live'' - real time
''final'' - final',
    id_subtipo        char(10)       null comment 'id_tipo = live
    arquivo - já existe novo
    live - atualizado

id_tipo = final
    arquivo - encerrado
    live - ainda aberto',
    sf_data           datetime       not null,
    sf_id_utilizador  int            null comment 'null - geral ; id_utilizador ut a que diz respeito',
    sf_id_cargo       char(100)      null,
    sf_tipo_processo  char(100)      not null,
    sf_id_tipo        char(100)      not null,
    sf_id_subtipo     char(100)      not null,
    sf_id_ramo        char(100)      not null,
    sf_id_seguradora  int            not null,
    sf_id_fraude      char(100)      null,
    sf_id_estado      char(100)      not null,
    data              date           not null,
    hora              time           null,
    n_diligencias_1   int            null,
    n_diligencias_0   int            null,
    sla_diligencias_1 int            null comment 'segundos',
    n_informacoes_1   int            null,
    n_informacoes_fp  int            null,
    n_informacoes_0   int            null,
    sla               decimal(11, 2) null,
    sla_fp            decimal(11, 2) null,
    estados_fp        tinyint(1)     null
);

create index lead_servico
    on _stats_leads_servicos (id_lead, id_servico);

create index seguradora
    on _stats_leads_servicos (sf_id_seguradora);

create index `sf_tipo-sf_subtipo`
    on _stats_leads_servicos (sf_id_tipo, sf_id_subtipo);

create index tipo
    on _stats_leads_servicos (id_tipo);

create index tipo_data
    on _stats_leads_servicos (id_tipo, data);

create index utilizador_cargo
    on _stats_leads_servicos (sf_id_utilizador, sf_id_cargo);
```

Comment: What statement is doing the lock timeout? What MariaDB version? What does `show processlist` and/or `show engine innodb status` show at the time the lock is waiting?

Comment: (Unrelated):  You should have a PRIMARY KEY.  When you have `INDEX(a,b), don't also have INDEX(a).  Use VARCHAR, not CHAR, unless the columns is really fixed length.